# Is Zpsycopg2 compatible with zope 2?

Tags: python, database, zope

I have zope 2.11 installed. Now i want to use Posgresql 7.4.13 DB with it. So i know i need to install psycopg2 Database Adapter. Can any one tell me Is psycopg2 compatible with zope2??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use psycopg2 with Zope2.

Just install it in your Python with easy_install or setup.py. You will also need a matching ZPsycopgDA Product in Zope. You find the ZPsycopgDA folder in the psycopg2 source distribution tarball.